# Selenium WebDriver driver issue Mac

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Selenium on a Mac and I have some issue concerning the drivers.
Here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I have downloaded chromedriver and put the file in my path. However when I try to launch a WebDriver instance I get the following error :

```
WebDriverException: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

So after a loads of research I tried this :

```
chromedriver = "/Users/luka1/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

However here again I run into an error which is :

```
LookupError: unknown encoding: idna
```

So I looked again and apparently the solution is to import encodings.idna, however when I try to do so I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings.idna'" (I do have the encodings module though).

I don't know how to solve this knowing that the chromedriver really is my path and every other solution fails. The code runs just great on my pc however. I also tried with gecko driver in case it was just a problem with Chrome but I have the same issue.

I use Anaconda and I have the Mac OS Mojave 10.14.3 version.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check this https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Comment: geckodriver is referring to Firefox.  Do you have Firefox installed?  I know you are trying to use Chrome, but Selenium defaults to Firefox.

Comment: I had a similar problem, put driver in the same folder as python file is and run it like that ( withou a path ) ;) if it fixes your problem, then you have a problem in path :)

Comment: @StyleZ Thanks for the tip but I already tried that and it does not work 
RKelley Yes I have Firefox installed and it did not work as well

Comment: Do you have idna installed?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Following command :**

```
brew install chromedriver
```

That should put the chromedriver in your path.

**Use Following Code :**

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROJECT_ROOT_DIR_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DRIVER_BIN_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR_PATH, "driver_Location/chromedriver_for_mac")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = DRIVER_BIN_PATH)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however when I did that I got the error : Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'; not linking. which means that I did put the file in the correct directory ... I really don't understand what's going on

Comment: I also deleted the file I initially copied in the Path and tried installing with Brew and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In MacOs follow the steps and u will get the chrome set up ::

First and foremost check if any Antivirus is running. If so, Disable it.

Second check the version of your chrome and make it latest to be in ur pc.

Third get the chrome driver for the version of chrome  u are using (like i used version 84 so got chrome driver for same version)and put the .exe file in the /usr/local/bin folder.

If u cant find the /usr/local/bin then go to the terminal type:: chflags nohidden ~/usr

Go to finder press CMD+Shift_G and go to the /usr/local/bin path and now paste the chrome driver .exe file.

Now it shall surely run the webdriver.Chrome()